# How to change /tmp directory path in Django?

Tags: django, kubernetes

So right now when I am trying to save a file in the DB in Django:

```
img_obj.image.save(img_file, File(img_file_org))
```

I am getting error that there is no space left.
I know that in my container (pod) it is being temporarily saved in `/tmp` folder while trying to save to the DB, to the correct folder where all the files are stored after successfully being saved which is set to '/code/data/media`using`MEDIA_ROOT`variable in django settings. However this`/tmp` folder is too small and I want to move it to my volume storage.
Any way to change that?